# TCP/IP Stream dumping text in arbitrary clumps (C Socket Programming)

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I am writing a chat application, both server and client side. Apologies for the long code. Presumably, I have misunderstood TCP/IP as a whole, yet I don't know where to start. The problem is that when several clients connect to the server, if many messages are sent to the server, there is not instantaneous delivery of messages to clients. What I can gather is that many messages are appended to a buffer on the server-side socket connection, and after an arbitrary number of messages, this buffer is dumped to one of the clients. This dump occurs immediately after a client hits Enter, so I assume there is problems in the multi-threading too.

My thoughts:

- Perhaps there is an alternative to tracking client connections on server-side than with file. A global file pointer could be better!! This seems good?
- TCP/IP is a pure data stream rather than packet transmission (message-by-message), so I should not treat it as so.
- Learn pthreads, more versatile.

(Also, I am having trouble with debugging using GDB attach function, hence I cannot debug my program :/ I am running Ubuntu 20.04, I would appreciate any help on this also)

CLIENT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int cli_sock, port;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char buffer[1024];

    port = atoi(argv[1]);

    if((cli_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("Socket failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Client socket initialised.\n");

    memset(&serv_addr, '\0', sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    if(connect(cli_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1) {
        printf("Client: ");
        fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);
        send(cli_sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
        if(strcmp(buffer, "/leave") == 0) {
            close(cli_sock);
            printf("Disconnected from server.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(recv(cli_sock, buffer, 1024, 0) < 0) {
            printf("Error in receiving data.\n");
        }
        else {
            if(sizeof(*buffer) == 1) { // prints data for all but sender.
                printf("%s", buffer);
            }
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

SERVER:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int fileLineCount(FILE *);
void deleteSockFromFile(FILE *, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int* senderID = calloc(1, sizeof(int));

    int serv_sock, port;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    int new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in new_addr;

    socklen_t addrlen;

    char buffer[1024];

    int roomSize;

    port = atoi(argv[1]);
    roomSize = atoi(argv[2]);

    if((serv_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("Server socket failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&serv_addr, '\0', sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    if(bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("Bind unsuccessful.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(serv_sock, roomSize) != 0) {
        printf("Listening...\n");
    }
    else {
        perror("Listening failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));

    FILE *clientsFile = NULL;
    if(!(clientsFile = fopen("clients.txt", "w+"))) { // file for tracking active client connections (socket fds)
        perror("Failed to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1) {
        new_sock = accept(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &new_addr, &addrlen);
        if(new_sock < 0) { //handling failed socket creation.
            perror("Socket failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

                printf("Connection accepted from %s:%d. Sock fd = %d\n", inet_ntoa(new_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(new_addr.sin_port), new_sock);

        printf("lineCount: %d\n", fileLineCount(clientsFile));

        fseek(clientsFile, 0, SEEK_END);
        fprintf(clientsFile, "%d\n", new_sock);

        printf("lineCount: %d\n", fileLineCount(clientsFile));

        if(fork() == 0) {
            close(serv_sock);

            while(1) {
                memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
                recv(new_sock, buffer, 1024, 0);
                if(strcmp(buffer, "/leave") == 0) {
                    printf("Disconnected from %s:%d.\n", inet_ntoa(new_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(new_addr.sin_port));
                    deleteSockFromFile(clientsFile, new_sock);
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Client: %s", buffer);

                    int temp_sock;
                    size_t length = 10;
                    char *line = calloc(length, sizeof(char));

                    rewind(clientsFile);

                    while(getline(&line, &length, clientsFile) >= 0) { // reads file with client sock fd
                        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
                        temp_sock = atoi(line); // set temp_sock to a client sock fd
                        if(temp_sock != new_sock) { // compares thread value of new_sock with all client socks, so the sender isn't sent the message, but everyone else is.
                            send(temp_sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                            printf("SHOULD SEND TO %d\n", temp_sock); //debugging line #1/2
                        }
                        else {
                            send(temp_sock, senderID, sizeof(senderID), 0);
                            printf("Should not send, cause sender.\n"); //debugging line #2/2
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }

    }
    fclose(clientsFile);
    remove("clients.txt");

    close(new_sock);

}

int fileLineCount(FILE *ptr) {

    int ch, lineCount = 0;

    fseek(ptr, 0, SEEK_SET);

    do {
            ch = fgetc(ptr);

            if(ch == '\n')
                lineCount++;

    }

    while (ch != EOF);

    return lineCount;
}

void deleteSockFromFile(FILE *ptr, int sock2delete) {

        size_t length = 10;

    char *line = calloc(length, sizeof(char));
    char *tempLine = calloc(length, sizeof(char));

    FILE *tempPtr = NULL;
    if((tempPtr = fopen("temp.txt", "w")) == 0) {
        perror("Unable to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    rewind(ptr); // must reset file cursor before switching from writing to reading mode (w+)

    while(getline(&line, &length, ptr) >= 0) {
        strcpy(tempLine, line);
        tempLine[strcspn(tempLine, "\n")] = 0; //remove newline char
        if(atoi(tempLine) != sock2delete) {
            fputs(line, tempPtr);
        }
    }

    remove("clients.txt");
    rename("temp.txt", "clients.txt");
    fclose(tempPtr);

    free(line);
    free(tempLine);

}
```

Here is test output for context, the test didn't go well, but as you can see only a small chunk of message went through (look @ top-left terminal, "c2" was received from client 2)[image]

(Perhaps this question should be renamed to GDB attach causes laptop to freeze when ran with sudo on multi-threading program using fork(), thoughts appreciated!)

Comment: `if(sizeof(*buffer) == 1)` is always true.

Comment: The buffer received from the server is either a char pointer or an int pointer, "buffer" is an unclear name I apologise, but when "buffer" is an int pointer, the size is 4, not 1.

Comment: `buffer[]` is a character array, so `buffer[0]` ( is equal to `*buffer`) is a chracter, indepent from what has (not) been recieved.

Comment: `if(strcmp(buffer, "/leave") == 0) {` will *never* be true (fgets() retains the \n)

Comment: You haven't read the server side code. All of these lines work as they are supposed to.

Comment: I've read it all. And believe me: it is full of misconceptions. (such as: expecting strings from read() recv(). Plus: memset() to the rescue... Not!)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that when several clients connect to the server, if many messages are sent to the server, there is not instantaneous delivery of messages to clients.

Your clients alternate between blocking on fgets(), waiting for input from stdin, and blocking on recv(), waiting for input from the server, so they'll only work if there's strict alternation between the two directions. A single call to `recv()` on a TCP socket can give you data written by multiple calls to `send()`, because TCP indeed is a byte stream, so you can get multiple messages at once (though you can't tell them apart). But `fgets()` gives you only one line at a time, if the client is waiting to receive something from the server, it wouldn't be able to read more input from stdin at the same time.

> Perhaps there is an alternative to tracking client connections on server-side than with file.

Storing file descriptor numbers in a file doesn't seem to make any sense at all. Fd numbers are just small integers, and their meaning is different for different processes. They're *not* globally unique identifiers!

You're forking a new process for each incoming connection. Each child process will get a copy of the file descriptors the server has open *at that time*. So, the first child will get the fd for the first client connection, the second child will get the fd's for the first two client connections, etc. But none of the children will ever get fd's for clients that come later, so you should be getting a number of errors for every time they attempt to write to fd's read from the file.

Forking a single child for each connection really only works if the clients don't need to interact directly. Also your child processes seem to fall out to the end of the whole `main` function if they ever get to break out of the inner `while(1)`, and the first to do so, will remove the `clients.txt` file. Even more, it looks like you're not paying any attention to the return values of the `recv()` calls, so if the remote closes the connection, you'll just spin forever on the `recv()`, which returns `0` marking "end of file".

---

Instead, you need to keep all the client fd's in a single server process, which can then read and write to/from all of them. Store their numbers in an array or such. Here, you're in the same situation as the client, you need to be able to monitor multiple fd's for input at the same time instead of blocking on one at a time. For that, you'll need to use `select()` (or `poll()`, or `epoll()`). The same goes for the client. There's an example for using `select()` in the GNU libc documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html

> TCP/IP is a pure data stream rather than packet transmission (message-by-message), so I should not treat it as so.

Yes, indeed. If the remote sends two lines with one `write()`/`send()` call each, say `hello!\n` and `how are you?\n`, the other end could in principle receive that in three parts: `hell`, `o!\nhow` and  `are you?\n`. There are no guarantees, though especially on a local network with light to no load, and with short messages, getting splitting like that would be quite unlikely. But the OS will give you the full `hello!\nhow are you?\n` in one go, if it was all received before the process got around to reading it. It's the job of the application to deal with finding out when it's received a complete line, and if there's anything after that.

Comment: This was infinitely helpful. Thank you sir.